# How to split name in label so only first two words appear?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, arcgis-10.2, labeling

The labels for my feature SSA_NAME are approximately 5 words long. I would like to shorten the labels to only 2 words. Every time I try a different code I receive either an error message or my layer is not labelled at all. Here is a code I tried based on another person's StackExchange question.

def convertLabel([SSA_NAME]):
         S= [SSA_NAME] 
         S = S.split(" ")[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cy0QE.jpg)
         return S

[image]

Comment: Hi @Aaron , I just tried replacing the [] with !! but I'm still receiving the same error. def convertLabel(!SSA_NAME!):
         S= !SSA_NAME! 
         S = S.split(" ")[1]
         return S

Comment: No, you just need !! in FieldCalculator, not in the label expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me and I have labeling only with 2nd word:

[image]

So maybe you have few atributres without " ", and you get "out of index".

```
def label([SSA_NAME]):
    x = [SSA_NAME]
    x1 = x.split(" ")
    if len(x1)>1:
        return x1[0] + " " + x1[1]
    else:
        return x1[0]
```

Comment: You should be able to shorten this to one line, no need for the FindLabel function: `[SSA_NAME].split(" ")[1]`  If you want the first two words, you could just use `[SSA_NAME].split(" ")[0] + " " + [SSA_NAME].split(" ")[1]` Or, slice the list with [:1], but that may create a funny looking string

Comment: @mr.adam, I just tried [SSA_NAME].split(" ")[1] but in 'basic' the error was "No Features found. Could not verify expression." 'Advanced' gave me a different error.

Comment: @dmh126, the code in your pasted pic worked for getting the second word but it did not allow the first and second to appear together. I tried [:1] instead of [1] but that just made the label disappear.

Comment: `return x1[0] + " " + x1[1]` should works

Comment: @dmh126, that did the trick. I'm new to coding so thank you!

Comment: @WolverineTime, I just tried that out and found the same thing. strange.  It does work with advanced and just using `return [SSA_NAME].split(" ")[1]`.  Anyway, glad you've got it figured out.